# Need to format my western digital drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, formatting

The problem I have is that I pluged my western digital elements portable hard drive into my bell sat receiver so that I could use it as a PVR. during the format process something went wrong. When I plug the drive into my computer now, the drive does not show up, however it does show up in my usb devices... Any ideas on how I can reformat it?

Answer (score 3):

If its Windows the problem might be a missing letter, open the start menu, run > diskmgmt.msc

A window will appear where you can right click your drive and assing it a letter, from there you can format it using the file explorer. On the file explorer right click on the drive and hit format :)

Comment: Or...you could just right-click the drive and format it straight from Disk Management...;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what OS you're using, but you should be able to boot with a Linux Live CD, and remove any existing partitions.  You can then create a new partition, and format the drive with the most appropriate file system.